# Python 3. Can I convert string which contains UTF-16 codes of characters ("0065") into string of UTF-16 characters "\u0065"?

Tags: python-3.x

I receive a string.

As example "00650053".

It is actually two characters 'e', 'S' encoded in "UTF-16"

Can I convert this string "00650053" into "\u0065\u0053" and print it as "eS"?

```
>>> print("\u0065\u0053")
eS
>>> print("00650053")
00650053
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm sure there's a way to do that, but it seems rather odd to get UTF-16 as a string. It might be easier to solve that. How did that happen?

Comment: Hello, I am a tester so i can't modify program. The solution of the problem was rather simple - bytes.fromhex("0065").decode('utf-8').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Turn the string into bytes.

That can be done with [bytes.fromhex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex).

```
>>> bytes.fromhex("00650053")
>>> b'\x00e\x00S'
```

2. Turn the bytes into UTF-16 BE.

That can be done with [bytes.decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode).

```
>>> bytes.fromhex("00650053").decode("utf-16be")
>>> 'eS'
```

Note that I had to specify the encoding "utf-16be" or big-endian. The order of UTF-16 is, unfortunately, dependent on how your CPU works. Lacking a byte-order-mark to tell which end is significant, it will use the native CPU endianness. Most personal computers are little-endian so it will read it as "utf-16le" which is `攀匀`. So we have to explicitly use "utf-16be".

Comment: Thank you, your note about "utf-16be" is very important for me. Because I've got "攀匀" and stuck on it. Then made wrong solution with - decode("utf-8") to avoid it.